# Как настроить перенаправление для страницы сайта php?

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess

Для страницы сайта с уникальным id необходимо настроить перенаправление его ссылки.
Структура ссылки: `site/page/index.php`

Как мне сделать, чтобы при открытии страницы с объявлением `site/page/?id=1` стало `site.ru/page/1`?

Пробовал так, но не получается:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/site/post/([0-9]+)/? /site/post/?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: `RewriteRule ^page/(\d+)/? page/index.php?id=$1 [L]` такое что ли? почему у вас то page то post

Comment: mod_rewrite у вас подключен?

Comment: Да, подключен! Но все равно не работает

Answer (score -1, accepted):

На основе уточненных данных предлагаю вариант:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/new/page/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule . /new/page/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/new/page/([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule . /new/page/index.php [L,QSA,NE]
```

Суть происходящего:

1. Делаем 301 редирект с /new/page/id=3 на /new/page/3
2. Передаем обработку скрипту по адресу /new/page/index.php
3. Подразумевается, что .htaccess находиться по адресу /new/.htaccess

Альтернативный вариант может быть:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/new/page/?id=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule . /new/page/$1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/new/page/([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule . /new/page/index.php [L,QSA,NE]
```

Но на XAMPP у меня не заработал.

P.S.
Рекомендую разворачивать каждый проект на отдельном домене, чтобы в подобных сценариях упростить себе жизнь.

Comment: 1-й вариант сработал! Спасибо большое!

Comment: и зачем делать 301 редирект?

Comment: А зачем минусовать, если не ознакомились с сутью вопроса? Была поставлена задача, предложен вариант, который ее решает. Может поделитесь великим опытом и продемонстрируете как автору достичь желаемого без редиректа?

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте в файл .htaccess добавить:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /page/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/?id=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1
```

Comment: К сожалению не получилось... не понимаю почему, сам htaccess работает, но че только не попробовал не получилось Открываю страницу вот так <a href='/new/page/?id=3'>Открыть запись</a> Открыть запись</a>

Comment: Изменил код, попробуйте теперь.

Comment: Все равно не получилось...url не изменился

Comment: У Вас есть путаница в вопросе. Сначала /site/page/, затем /site/post/. Сейчас уже /new/page/.

Comment: Ой да, в итоге page. Действительно запутал, сейчас объясню еще раз: сайт находится в каталоге new/index.php, есть страница объявления которая находится в папке page/index.php в итоге new/page, с id new/page/?id=3

Comment: Где находится .htaccess? И приведите полностью URL-адрес запроса.

Comment: htaccess находится в главной папке сайта по пути new/.htaccess
url http://localhost:8888/new/page/?id=3

Comment: Попробовал только что вот так, изменения есть в url но результат пока что не тот: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /new/page?id=$1 [L]

Comment: Создается впечатление, что Вам требуется редирект, в первую очередь. Вы же хотите с localhost:8888/new/page/?id=3 перейти на localhost:8888/new/page/3, верно? А после этого, судя по всему, обработка запроса должна быть передана скрипту localhost:8888/new/page/index.php, так?

Comment: да, верно
просто мне нужно изменить url вид на тот что я описал выше

Comment: Это два RewriteRule, первый должен делать редирект, а второй перенаправлять на скрипт.

Comment: Файл .htaccess необходимо положить в директорию localhost:8888/new/page/